# Integrating to find Streamlines containing two Variables

Tags: calculus, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I'm attempting to find the streamlines for a fluid flow given by the fluid velocity
$\mathbf{u} = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ -z + \cos{\omega t} \\ y + \sin{\omega t} \end{bmatrix}$.

I have formulated the 2 differential equations:

$$\frac{dx}{0}=\frac{dy}{-z+\cos(\omega t)}=\frac{dz}{y+\sin(\omega t)}$$

From this I know that $x=c_1$, where $c_1$ is an arbitrary constant. But how do I solve the rest?

Am I correct in saying that the remainder of the equation would yield:

$$(y+\sin{\omega t}) \space dy=(-z+\cos\omega t)\space dz$$

But this surely can't be right because I cannot integrate any $f(t)$ with respect to $y$ or $z$, can I?

Comment: You shouldn't parameterise your streamline with $t$ in this case.

Comment: @CheeHan, this parameterisation is given to me though? The only information I have for the fluid flow is the given $\mathbf{u}$

Comment: True, but streamline is, by definition, a curve that is everywhere tangent to the flow field at a given time $t$. The crucial point here is that it is different compare to pathline (in the case of unsteady flow). So we parameterise the streamline with variable, say $s$ instead of $t$, to distinguish it from solving for the pathline.